# || operator is same as = operator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I saw this excerpt in the agile rails programming book:

```
module StoreHelper 
def page_title 
@page_title || "Pragmatic Store" 
end 
end
```

Can I change || to =?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The longer answer is that you've stumbled on a programming style which is popular because it's very concise, yet still easy to understand.  It's a shortcut way to write:

```
if ! @page_title.nil?
  return @page_title
else
  return "Pragmatic Store"
end
```

So that one line with logical or's removes the need for an if/then. It does this because of the way that || is evaluated: from left-to-right, stopping at the first item that's not false. The example you found also leaves out the *return* keyword, because it's not explicitly necessary here.

Answer (score 4):

No.

That means that `page_title` will return `@page_title` if not nil, **OR** `"Pragmatic Store"` if `@page_title` is nil. (nil is null)

Comment: Or nil. 15 character commentttnwjiqiqhheififjhf

Comment: Also notice that in Ruby, if a statement is given without any function but within a function or method, it's returned automatically.

Comment: @Time Machine: if it is the last line of that method

Comment: Doesn't have to be if the last statement is an `if-then-else`, right?